# How to achieve image straightening as cam scanner does?

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

Is it possible to achieve image straightening as [cam scanner](https://www.camscanner.com/) does

[image]

I mean selecting a non-rectangular region and converting it to a rectangular region as an image. I can only do re sizing and crop of rectangular region of image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Geometric Transformation

Supose that $f$ is an image, defined over $(w,z)$ coordinate system, undergoes geometric distortion to produce an image $g$, defined over $(x,y)$ coordinate system. To perform this operation is used this

$$(x,y) = T\{(w,z)\} $$

So, one of most commmonly used forms of spatial transformation is the *affine transform* (Wolberg [1990]). It can be written in the matrix form as

$$ [x \ y \ 1] = [w \  z \ 1] \ \mathbf{T} = [w \  z \ 1] 
\left[ { \begin{array}{ccc}
         t_{11} & t_{12} & 0 \\ 
         t_{21} & t_{22} & 0 \\ 
         t_{31} & t_{32} & 1 \\ 
        \end{array}} \right]$$

This transformation can scale, rotate, translate or shear a set of points, depending on the values choosen for the elements of $\mathbf{T}$

**Your case: Perspective Transformation**

For perspective transformation, you need a 3x3 transformation matrix. Straight lines will remain straight even after the transformation. To find this transformation matrix, you need 4 points on the input image and corresponding points on the output image. Among these 4 points, 3 of them should not be collinear.

### Implementations

#### Python

- OpenCV

OpenCV has a lot of methods to perform image warping and geometric transformation an you can get the examples in the [docs](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) page

- scikit-image

scikit-image also have many examples in the [documation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_geometric.html) page.

For python just choose the module more comfortable to you or use both.

- MATLAB ® Image Processing Toolbox

As the others examples the Math Work's software have a lot of functions to perform geometric transformation. Beware that is an commercial software and it not have a strong programming language if you want make a little software.

### References

**Wolberg [1990]** *G. Wolberg. Digital Image Warping . IEEE Computer Society Press, 1990.*

**Gonzalez [1987]** *Gonzalez, R.C., P. Wintz, 1987. Digital Image Processing. 2nd Ed., Addison-Wesley, Reading:MA.*

#### Futher Reading

This [lecture](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/lectures/lecture07-Affine.pdf) is a good introduction to this process